# Is A∨¬A a tautology when there is a proof (by contradiction)?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

$A \lor \neg A$ is stated as a "tautology", but is it really a tautology? It can be proven by counterposition. And therefore it is not a tautology when it can be proven(?)

### Update

Here's the proof (by contradiction) I mean:

```
¬(A∨¬A) (assumption)
   A      (assumption)
   A∨¬A  (rule of introduction)
  人      (contradiction)
 ¬A
 A∨¬A   (rule of introduction)
 人      (contradiction)
¬¬(A∨¬A)
A∨¬A
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.Why do you think $A \vee \neg A$ isn't a tautology?

Comment: How is your proof that it is not ?

Comment: Make a truth table, it cannot be proven otherwise as you will see

Comment: @GitGud A tautology is e.g. "A=A" and there's a difference between tautology and truth.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but $1=1$ isn't a tautology.

Comment: @GitGud Why isn't "1=1" a tautology? I could've misunderstood.

Comment: @ashley I added the proof where I assume it's false and derive a contradiction so we don't take "A∨¬A" for granted.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz It seems to me that you think that a tautology can't be proven, but it can. In fact, one possible definition of tautology is a statement which can be proven without any hypothesis. To check that the statement $1=1$ isn't a tautology, construct its truth table. Ignore the meaning of $1$, $+$ and $=$. Just make a truth table for an arbitrary statement $A$ and then let $A$ mean $1=1$.

Comment: Um, I hate to wade into this deep philosophical discussion, but why do you have a couple of [Han characters for people](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4eba/index.htm) in your proof? The usual symbol for a contradiction is the [up tack](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22a5/index.htm), $\bot$.

Comment: @ℝⁿ 人 was just the symbol my logic teacher was using. The textbook was by Graeme Forbes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$A\vee \neg A$ is a tautology in classical (i.e., Aristotelian) logic because you can prove that using the deduction rules of the classical proposition calculus no matter what the truth value of $A$ is, the truth value of $A\vee \neg A$ is always true. That is the meaning of tautology.

In non-classical logical systems, such as intuitionism or constructivism, $A \vee \neg A$ is not a tautology. There the interpretation of $P \vee Q$ is not "either P or Q is true" but rather the more constructive "Either I have a proof of P or I have a proof of Q". A famous example to illustrate this is the following: Theorem: There exist two irrational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational. A classical proof can go like this: if $\sqrt2 ^\sqrt2$ is rational we are done. Else, consider $(\sqrt2^{\sqrt2})^{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2^2=2$, a rational. Classically this finishes the proof but constructively it is not a valid proof since it does not actually show which one of the two candidates works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the proof I was thinking of.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss don't you mean $\displaystyle \bigl(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2} \bigr)^\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: This is why I would call $A\  \or\  \not A$ an **axiom** rather than a tautology in most uses of first order predicate calculus, but not all. For example, the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra holds for the constructive complex numbers.

Comment: @BarbaraOsofsky \neg to get $\neg$ and \vee to get $\vee$.

Comment: I prefer $\\lor$ for $\lor$ so I was willing to accept that missing letter, but thanks for pointing out the $\\neg$.  I find inputting the LaTeX the hardest part of commenting expecially since in commenting I cannot see the mathjax and there is a strict time limit on editing and only 2 edits.

Comment: `\lnot` also works for $\lnot$.  But that `l` is important.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the problem here may be that "tautology" has a far more specific meaning in mathematical logic than in ordinary usage.  The more specific meaning is "a statement S that always true, solely on the basis of how S is constructed from smaller statements by means of propositional connectives and the meanings (truth tables) of the connectives".  So $A\lor\neg A$ is a tautology because it is true solely because of the meanings of $\lor$ and $\neg$.  But $1=1$ is not a tautology because its truth depends on the meaning of $=$, which is not a propositional connective.  Similarly, if $P$ is a unary predicate, then $P(a)\to(\exists x)\,P(x)$, though logically valid, is not a tautology because its validity depends on the meanings of both $\to$ and $\exists$, the latter of which is not a propositional connective.

In ordinary, non-technical usage, "tautology" means (according to my dictionary) saying the same thing in different words; I've heard it used more generally to mean anything that is obviously true.  So all of the examples in my first paragraph would be tautologies in this sense.

Comment: plus the fact that the sub-statements (values) are *bi-valent*

Answer (score 4):

Try constructing a truth table and you will see that it is in fact a tautology.

Comment: But what's the difference then between tautologies and truths?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz A tautology is a statement which truth table is always true. A logical truth is a statement that is always true *after* you interpret its meaning. For instance, if I say that "every goba is esdel or not every goba is esdel" you know that this is true even though you don't know what a goba or an esdel are. The statement $1=1$ is a logical truth and you know that only after knowing the meaning of $1$, $+$ and $=$.

Comment: @GitGud 'If I say that "every goba is esdel or not every goba is esdel" you know that this is true even though you don't know what a goba or an esdel are.' Not so. The most you know is that if it is a contentful English sentence, then it expresses a truth. But if you don't know whether it is contentful, you can't know whether it is true.

Comment: @PeterSmith I get what you're saying and I love such detail. However I chose to keep things simpler by taking a "statement" in english, I think it's an easier way to make things clearer. I'm going to e-mail one of these days, by the way.

Comment: @PeterSmith *e-mail you

Comment: @PeterSmith I think that we can't say it's true with no proof.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to know if a proposition such as $A \lor \lnot A$ is a tautology if it can be proven. The OP provided a proof so the answer depends on the definition of *tautology*. Here is [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)):

> In logic, a tautology ... is a formula or assertion that is true in every possible interpretation.

For propositional logic [Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpretations_for_propositional_logic) an *interpretation* as follows:

> The standard kind of interpretation in this setting is a function that maps each propositional symbol to one of the truth values true and false.

Such interpretations can be illustrated with truth tables. For $A \lor \lnot A$ we have the following truth table showing that for all interpretations the proposition is true and hence the proposition is a tautology:

[image]

Since propositional logic has derivation systems that are both [sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) and [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)).  Any tautology can be derived in such systems because they are complete. Any derivation in such systems can be formatted as a tautology in a truth table because they are sound.

For example, given the premises $P$, $P \implies Q$ one can derive $Q$. If one conjoins the premises and connects these conjoined premises and the conclusion with a conditional symbol, one can see from a truth table that it will also be a tautology.  For this example, here is the truth table:

[image]

One should expect to be able to derive any tautology in propositional logic in a sound and complete derivation system for propositional logic.

---

Michael Rieppel. Truth Table Generator. https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, April 30). Interpretation (logic). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 12:30, August 6, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interpretation_(logic)&oldid=894912837

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, June 21). Tautology (logic). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 12:15, August 6, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tautology_(logic)&oldid=902843519